# Linking OpenCV library (ROS2, C++)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I'd like to use the OpenCV library in a C++ project - ROS2 (building with colcon build).

I added in the CmakeList the following command:

> find_package(OpenCV 3.4.0 REQUIRED)

And when I #include any OpenCV header in my main code, I have no errors, but when I call any function of it, I have linking errors. It may be missing something in the CmakeList, but I don't know exactly what...

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359617/linking-opencv-library-(ros2,-c++)/) by [mirella melo](https://answers.ros.org/users/55539/mirella-melo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 194 on 2020-08-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Teo Cardoso](https://answers.ros.org/users/31965/teo-cardoso/) on 2020-08-15**:
Are you linking the OpenCV library in the 'target_link_libraries' section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Add OpenCV in ament target dependencies-

```
ament_target_dependencies(executable_name 
  rclcpp 
  OpenCV
..
..
..
other _packages
)
```

---

Originally posted by [Harsh2308](https://answers.ros.org/users/31217/harsh2308/) with karma: 80 on 2020-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mirella melo](https://answers.ros.org/users/55539/mirella-melo/) on 2020-08-16**:
Thank you, guys!! It is working. o/

**Comment by [psammut](https://answers.ros.org/users/31213/psammut/) on 2022-06-01**:
How did you know to add `OpenCV`? Are there docs on this?